# Method is not called when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, eventemitter

In the below code I am learning the event emitters and output decorators.

The problem I am facing now is, when I click the button as shown below:

```
<button (click)="emitValueToParentComponent">CLICK to emit value</button>
```

the method emitValueToParentComponent never gets called and the console.log does not print anything on the browser's console.

Please let me know how to call the method emitValueToParentComponent on button click

```js
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-student',
      templateUrl: './student.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./student.component.css']
    })
    export class StudentComponent implements OnInit {

      @Input() myInputText : string;
      @Output() mOutputEvtEmitterFromStudentToParentComponent: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
      valueToEmit: string = "emitted value from child student component to parent component";
      
      constructor() {
       }
     
      ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log("ngOnInit myInputText: " + this.myInputText);
      }

      emitValueToParentComponent() {
        this.mOutputEvtEmitterFromStudentToParentComponent.emit(this.valueToEmit);
        console.log("emitValueToParentComponent valueToEmit: " + this.valueToEmit);
        console.log("emitted value");
      }
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <button (click)="emitValueToParentComponent">CLICK to emit value</button>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div>
<button (click)="emitValueToParentComponent()">CLICK to emit value</button>

</div>
```

You need to actually call the function `emitValueToParentComponent()` on click.Passing `reference` like that is a part of react ecosytem.